# Superelliptical Trig Functions

Tags: trigonometry

The six normal trigonometric functions relate to the unit circle and the coordinates of the endpoints of the radii making some angle $\theta$ with the x-axis (sine represents the y-coordinate, cosine the x-coordinate, and tangent the ratio of the two). Does there exist a analogous set of functions for the unit superellipse with equation
$$x^4+y^4=1?$$
I've been struggling to define such functions that are periodic and work for all values of $\theta$, $0$ through $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=1$ can be described as $(\cos{t},\sin{t})$, so $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=1$ can be described as $(\sqrt[n]{\cos{t}},\sqrt[n]{\sin{t}})$ for $0<t<\frac{\pi}{2}$. To generalize this to all $t$, we can multiply by the signum function, which returns $1$ or $-1$ depending on the sign of the input, and we have
$$(signum(\cos{t})\sqrt[n]{|\cos{t}|},signum(\sin{t})\sqrt[n]{|\sin{t}|})$$

Comment: I see that, but how do I make sure that it is defined for all angles from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: Well, you could use a piecewise function if nothing else works.

Comment: That's true, I could define it in that way.

Comment: I came up with a slightly nicer method.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to expand upon the excellent solution presented by @IsaacBrowne. To that end, I introduce my own generalization of the superellipse, called superconics. The general form is given by

$$f(X) = b(1-c^2|X/a|^q)^p$$

or its canonical form

$$f(x) = (1-c^2|x|^q)^p$$

Here, $a$ and $b$ scale the $x$ and $y$ axes, resp. and $c^2=\pm1$. $c^2=1$ corresponds to elliptic and parabolic types and $c^2=-1$ corresponds to hyperbolic types. (More generally, $c^2$ can vary smoothly between.)

The following integral gives the area under the curve, the centroid, moments, and moments of inertia of all the superconics.

$$\int_{-a}^a X^nf^m(X) dX = a^{n+1}b^m\int_{-1}^1 x^nf^m(x) dx$$

First we notice that $a$ and $b$ are superfluous and that we can concentrate on the canonical equation. The results can be scaled appropriately for any $a$ and $b$ afterward according to the factor $a^{n+1}b^m$. Next, and most important, this equation can be solved exactly in terms of known functions, specifically, the Gauss hypergeometric function and the incomplete beta function

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 x^nf^m(x) dx
& = \frac{2}{n+1} {_2F_1}(-mp,\frac{n+1}{q};1+\frac{n+1}{q};c^2)\\
& = \frac{2}{q} (c^2)^{-\frac{n+1}{q}} B(\frac{n+1}{q},mp+1,c^2)
\end{align}
$$

Further simplifications accrue when $c^2=1$. To wit, for $m=1, n=0$ we get the area

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \Psi(p,q) = 2\frac{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(1+1/q)}{\Gamma(1+1/q)}  = \Psi(1/q,1/p)$$

More generally, for arbitrary $m$ and $n$ we substitute $p\to mp$ and $q\to q/(n+1)$. All of the integrals for $c^2=1$ can be expressed solely in terms of the parameter $\Psi$. This is true for bodies of revolution as well as other three-dimensional bodies composed of superconics profiles.

Now, in addition to the above intrinsic equation for the superconics, we can derive the following $parametric$ equation for superconics in the complex plane:

$$z=|\cos^{2/q}(u)|\text{sgn}(\cos(u))+i|(1-c^2\cos(u))^p|\text{sgn}(\sin(u))$$

where $u = [0,\pi]$ for the upper half plane and $u = [0,2\pi]$ for the full plane, e.g., a closed curve.

You can find some illustrations and animations of superconics here [Superconics](http://web.calstatela.edu/curvebank/superconicncb/superconicncb.htm) and here [A New Twist on Möbius](http://web.calstatela.edu/curvebank/moebius2/moebius2.htm). There is even an animation of a smooth transition from a sphere to a hyperboloid of one and two sheets using only superconics (with variable $c^2$). Here is a small version of that animation. Mind you, we can make similar animations with *any* superconics shape.

[image: The Hyperspheroid]

In the spirit of full disclosure, this is essentially the same response as used here: [Polar form of generalized superellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586468/polar-form-of-generalized-superellipse).