# Length of circumference and/or area by intersection of torus and plane

Tags: curves, arc-length

I found a [model](https://www.geogebra.org/m/MmTVuXYk) by [Luca Moroni](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00803) and would like to get the length of the circumference and/or the area of the intersection. Unfortunately Luca himself couldn't help me.

As i understand, the curve for the intersection at geogebras model is given by the so called "implicit curve" "ftw" and using geogebras function such as "lenght(ftw)" returns an error like "Argument not supported: Implicit curve"

Would be great, if somebody could help me getting this through geogebra. I don't know if it is of any help geogebra can get the length of parametric curves such as "length(ParametricCurve,Start,Stop)"

I recognized something [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858275/help-regarding-the-area-and-length-of-an-implicit-curve), but i'm not sure if this could be adapted to this specific case.

Many thanks in advance.